# Moving "Workspace Switcher" in Ubuntu Unity Launcher

Tags: desktop, ubuntu-unity, launcher, switching

I need the Workspace Switcher in Unity's Launcher at the very top just below Dash or Nautilus. I need this because when I run VirtualBox the commands <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>/<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> are not available and so need to get to the desktop switcher to speed up things.

Since my Launcher is crowded, I need to scroll the launcher to switch to a different workspace, which is a waste since I run a fullscreen emulator in one window and gnome terminals and browsers in another, and need to *switch* frequently.

**How do I place the Desktop Switcher at the top of Unity launcher?** For other apps you just long-mouse-press and then drag, but I am not able to drag the workspace switcher. The same is true for Dash and the Trashcan -- everything else I can move, but not the desktop switcher. Was wondering if there's an XML file somewhere on the filesystem where I can configure such behavior.

Comment: Seeing you received no answer within 16 hours: You might want to try asking on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) (or request to have your question migrated to that place).

Comment: Sure, how can I have my question migrated?

Comment: I never did that myself, but this question is handled at meta: [How do I properly migrate my question](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/how-do-i-properly-migrate-my-question). To make it short: you can "flag" it to be migrated (see the "flag" link directly below your questions tags).

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is not possible to move the location of the Workspace switcher in the Unity launcher. Follow the relevant [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+bug/761155) for updates.

Since you cannot use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> inside of the VirtualBox, you can perhaps use <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, which mimics the functionality of the Workspace Switcher.

**Update**

From Unity 6.6 onwards, you can now move the Workspace switcher icon.

[image: Workspace icon]